# Como é que posso usar este código?

Tags: python

```
import socket, sys, os  
print "][ Attacking " + sys.argv[1]  + " ... ]["  
print "injecting " + sys.argv[2];  
def attack():  
    #pid = os.fork()  
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
    s.connect((sys.argv[1], 80))  
    print ">> GET /" + sys.argv[2] + " HTTP/1.1"  
    s.send("GET /" + sys.argv[2] + " HTTP/1.1\r\n")  
    s.send("Host: " + sys.argv[1]  + "\r\n\r\n");  
    s.close()  
for i in range(1, 1000):  
    attack()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes no terminal fazer:

```
python ficheiro.py www.google.com 123
```

Aviso-te desde já que não vai fazer o que estás à espera, não vai haver nenhum ddos... É bom que saibas que não devias tentar essas coisas sem autorização do proprietário do sistema (`sys.argv[1]`)

Comment: Como poderia fazer um DDos em ambiente controlado para uso acadêmico?

Comment: Há imensa na internet, e se perceber bem inglês não vejo porque não encontrar o que quer. Pode começar por entender bem o que é: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_nega%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_servi%C3%A7o